# image upload in asp.net razor website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have a form where you enter information about the picture and upload it, the upload code in the html form is :

```
 @FileUpload.GetHtml(
                initialNumberOfFiles: 1,
                allowMoreFilesToBeAdded: false,
                includeFormTag: false,
                uploadText: "Upload");
```

and in the c# code in the same page i got :

```
                            var fileName = "";
                            var fileSavePath = "";
                            var uploadedFile = Request.Files[0];
                            fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
                            fileSavePath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/inscriptions/" +
                            fileName);
                            uploadedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
```

for some reason i get the error "index out of range" on the line :

```
var uploadedFile = Request.Files[0];
```

i want the user to click browse choose the file and fill the other Text boxes and click save to upload the picture and fill the info in the database(which is handled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out your problem may be solved with one of these solutions:

**Solution 1**: Change `includeFormTag: false` to `includeFormTag: true`.

```
@FileUpload.GetHtml(
            initialNumberOfFiles: 1,
            allowMoreFilesToBeAdded: false,
            includeFormTag: true,
            uploadText: "Upload");
```

This solution apply if `FileUpload` helper placed outside any `form` tag.

**Solution 2**: Use `Html.BeginForm` with attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` that wraps `FileUpload` helper.

```
using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @FileUpload.GetHtml(
            initialNumberOfFiles: 1,
            allowMoreFilesToBeAdded: false,
            includeFormTag: false,
            uploadText: "Upload");
}
```

This solution apply if you don't want to create new form tag by `FileUpload` helper and use existing form instead.

NB: `IndexOutOfRangeException` on `Request.Files[0]` originated from form submission request which omitted file part contained in `<input type="file" />`, hence you need to include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute (see explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean/4526286#4526286)).

Related problems:

[How to use @FileUpload.GetHtml inside Html.BeginForm and sumbit FilesList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282988/how-to-use-fileupload-gethtml-inside-html-beginform-and-sumbit-fileslist)

[Trying to work with Request.Files in WebMatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037172/trying-to-work-with-request-files-in-webmatrix)

Comment: Thanks i just added the enctype part to my existing form and it worked!